# Examples of Push APIs

Tags: api, server-push

Looking for examples of Push APIs, other than the websocket or the comet or the pubsub. 
Need examples specifically for communication between two systems (versus Client/Browser - Server). In other words it doesn't have to be over HTTP.

Comment: The API used in many web socket implementations is the same as non websocket approaches. Specifically, Pub/Sub isn't websocket specific and can be used in many different contexts, including peer2peer gossip environments.

Answer (score 2):

[PubSubHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) A simple, open, server-to-server web-hook-based pubsub (publish/subscribe) protocol as an extension to Atom and RSS.

They also have a wiki page for [comparing different protocols](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/ComparingProtocols).

Comment: Thanks. I am actually looking for something other than Atom or RSS feeds. Looking for apis to move large amount of data between two systems...and doesn't have to be HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are several somewhat evolved APIs for this. [Here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuery-Comet-Push-API) is one for jQuery. [Here](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/07/08/creating-comet-applications-with-aspnet/) is a blog post describing how to implement this in ASP.NET. It's a difficult framework to idea due to that pesky constant connectivity thing.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I did notice I wasn't clear on my post. Looking for examples of APIs between systems/servers - ideally for large amount of data..and dont have to be over HTTP.

Comment: If you're looking for an efficient client-server model, look at either java.nio or Twisted Python and just make up you're own protocol. If you don't require a browser, this whole problem is so much easier. Generally, the only non-HTTP protocol in the browser is WebSockets, but that's not nailed down quite yet